# How to create an Automator service to run a script on all files in a folder

Tags: automator, script

I want to create a service using Automator to run a shell script on all files in a folder, say delete all log files. What I have done is

1. Created a new service in automator.
2. Added a "Run Shell Script" action. I have change this to 'pwd' for now.
3. Selected "Service receives selected folders".
4. Tried to run it, but get a message. "To test this service within Automator, add the "Get Specified Finder Items" action to the beginning of your workflow. Remove or disable the action before running the workflow outside of Automator.
5. OK. So I add "Get Specified Finder Items". Added a 'test' directory to the list of items.

Now, when I run the script, the results window prints out my home directory.

Elsewhere, I have read that I maybe need to add

```
cd "$1"
```

to the beginning of my script. I did that but it still prints my home directory. How do I get this thing to print the directory I have selected in "Get Specified Finder Items?"

Edited to Add

Here is a screen shot of a script that works.

[image: test]

Here is a screen shot os a script that doesn't work.

[image]

The usual way I would deal with the "no match found : *.log" error would be to redirect error output to null. Replacing the "rm" line by

```
find . -name "*.log" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Does work though. This seems more difficult than it should be.

Comment: I'v updated my answer to show you a working example, have a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 9):

If you're creating a **Service** using **RunShell Script** which you want to pass the selected **Folder(s)** to the **RunShell Script** and have additional actions take place in the *script* on them, then start with these settings.

**Create the Service:**

1. Open **Automator** and select **Service** or **File** > **New** > **Service** If **Automator** is already open.
2. Set **Service receives selected** to **folders** and **in** to **Finder**.
3. Add a **Run Shell Script** *Action*, setting **Shell:** to **/bin/bash** and **Pass input:** to
    **as arguments**.  This changes the default *code* to from `cat` to:

   ```
    for f in "$@"
    do
        echo "$f"
    done
   ```

Now you can use `$f` to act on the target **Folder(s)**, e.g. `cd $f` and now you're in the directory of `$f` and can add additional *code* to act upon the files/folders within `$f`, etc.

**Update:**

Use the following *working code* as an example:

```
for d in "$@"; do
    cd "$d" || exit
    for f in *.log; do 
        [ -f "$f" ] || continue   
        rm "$f"
    done
done
```

Within the **Test** and **Test copy** folders there were a number of **.log** files and files with other extensions as well.  When the above code was run it deleted only the ***.log** files within the target folders as show in the images below using two folders or one folder and both files and folders with/without spaces in their names.

**Note:** The screen shots below do not contain the *error handling* that was added to the *example* **shell script** *code* per comments to this answer.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works. The bit I was missing was "Pass input: as arguments". However, when I add the lines cd $1, rm *.log 2>/dev/null fails with an error "Run Shell Script failed - 1 error" and nothing more enlightening.

Comment: @pheon, Trying to troubleshoot someone's _code_ without a proper [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is difficult. Also when using a Run Shell Script, there should be no need to use redirects like `2>/dev/null`. If you're trying to `cd` to the Folder passed to the Automator Service you should be using the `for` loop and `cd $f`` as I said, not `cd $1`. Read the mcve and add additional information to your question so as to enable proper troubleshooting, otherwise there is not much I can do.  You also need to add a screenshot of _code_ being used as it's written in your Automator service.

Comment: This fails for me if there are no .log files in the folder.

Comment: @pheon. Please understand that _code_ provided is example/sample _code_ and is often minimal to show that something can work.  The onus is on the _user_ to write appropriate error checking _code_ and implement it. I'll look at it sometime this weekend and modify/add error checking to the existing example/sample _code_ .

Comment: I appreciate that it is more complicated than I first thought. I admit I thought it was going to be easy. I was using this as an exercise in learning automator. The frustrating thing is that a bash shell script that works from the terminal does not translate directly into automator and automator does not give useful diagnostic messages when that script fails. Thanks for your help. From here, it is only necessary to help solve the problem if you enjoy the puzzle; I'll find a work around by using the bash script as intended.

Comment: @pheon, Sorry the add _error handling_ fell thru the cracks. 5 years late, but I finally added it. :)