# Run ffmpeg to remove exif on several files at once

Tags: video

Is there a way of removing exif for several files at once?

`ffmpeg -i in.mov -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mov` worked great for me as I wanted to remove date-stamped details from an MTS video file, but I have to do it from a list of videos and wanted to know if there was a script I could use to avoid processing each file (specify outputs "manually") one by one and get outputs like "video 1.MTS, video 2.MTS,..." and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with `for f in /path/*.MTS; do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "$f copy.MTS" 
done`
and came up with files like "video 1.MTS copy.MTS" which work just fine and with no timestamp.

There might be a more logical way to do it but as I'm no expert when it comes to shell script I'm gonna stick with this one in case I need it again.

Thanks to Graham Miln for helping, cheers everyone !

Comment: Please could you [mark the answer as accepted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). That will help others know this question has been answered and has a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

See [Run script on multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858896) for a few approaches to this problem. Given the accepted answer in the linked question, you might write:

```
for f in /input_path/*.MTS; do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "out/$f"
done
```

## Automator

You could use Automator to allow easier selection of the input files, see [user3439894's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232211/1860):

[image: Automator]

## Many Approaches

Other approaches are discussed in these questions:

- [How to create an Automator service to run a script on all files in a folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232205/how-to-create-an-automator-service-to-run-a-script-on-all-files-in-a-folder)
- [Run a script over multiple files in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087843/run-a-script-over-multiple-files-in-unix)
- [Batch convert .ai to .svg using Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485012/batch-convert-ai-to-svg-using-mac-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The automation command seem to work fine event though I had to change the "out" part for `for f in /my_input_path/*.MTS; do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "$f"
done ` but then for an unknown reason my videos are left with 0 octets, empty, can't be played... I ran some tests and it seems like I can't just overwrite the files but really create new ones, I know it must only be a matter of replacing the "$f" part with something but I have no clue what... Any ideas ?